# ASP.NET 5 (vNext) - Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to learn ASP.NET 5. I am using it on Mac OS X. At this time, I have a config.json file that looks like the following:

**config.json**

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Environment":"dev"
    },

    "DbSettings": {
        "AppConnectionString": "..."
    },

    "EmailSettings": {
        "EmailApiKey": "..."        
    },  
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to load these settings into a configuration file in Startup.cs. Currently, I have a file that looks like this:

**Configuration.cs**

```
public class AppConfiguration
{
    public AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public DbSettings DbSettings { get; set; }

    public EmailSettings EmailSettings { get; set; }        
}

public class AppSettings
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }
}

public class DbSettings
{
    public string AppConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class EmailSettings
{
    public string MandrillApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in Startup.cs, I have the following:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
  var configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile("config.json");
  Configuration = configuration;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

However, this approach doesn't work. Basically, its like it doesn't know how to map between the .json and the Config classes. How do I do this?

I would really like to stay with the DI approach so I can test my app more effectively.

Thank you

Comment: @KamranShahid That does not address this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Startup` class, first specify your configuration sources:

```
private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    configuration = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
}
```

*The `env.EnvironmentName` is something like `"development"` or `"production"`.  Suppose it is `"development"`. The framework will try to pull configuration values from `config.development.json` first. If the requested values aren't there, or the `config.development.json` file doesn't exist, then the framework will try to pull the values from `config.json`.*

Configure your `config.json` sections as services like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSubKey("AppSettings"));
    services.Configure<DbSettings>(configuration.GetSubKey("DbSettings"));
    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSubKey("EmailSettings"));
}
```

*Calling `Configure<T>(IConfiguration)` on the `IServiceCollection` registers the type `IOptions<T>` in the dependency injection container. Note that you don't need your `AppConfiguration` class.*

Then specify dependencies to be injected like this:

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings;

    public EmailController (IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings)
    {
        this.emailSettings = emailSettings;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string apiKey = emailSettings.Options.EmailApiKey;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I currently have. However, I wanted to have a wrapper class (i.e. `AppConfiguration`) because I intend to have more sections in the config file. I do not want to have to inject a bunch of dependencies each time. In an attempt to keep my code clean and concise, I want to use a single wrapper class (`AppConfiguration`) so that I only need to inject a single dependency.

Comment: The updated approach is not working for me. Oddly, I can see the property values in intellisense. However, the following confirms that DbSettings is null. `     if (appConfiguration.Options.DbSettings == null)
  Console.WriteLine("db config has not been set");
else
  Console.WriteLine("db app config is set");
`

Comment: @ZachTempleton Ah sorry, I have rolled back that addition.  It looks like it doesn't support that (yet?).

Comment: Ah ha. It is supported. Here's a blog post. http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/03/Strongly-typed-AppSettings-Configuration-in-ASPNET-5

Comment: It seems that GetSubKey is has been deprecated.  Now I can't seem to figure out how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access the value of config property `Environment` by using `Configuration` class like this anywhere in your application.

```
var environment = Configuration["AppSettings:Environment"];
```

But if you want it to access through a property of class you can do this

```
public class AppSettings 
{ 
 public string Environment
 { 
 get 
 { 
  return new Configuration().Get("AppSettings:Environment").ToString(); 
 }
 set; 
 } 
}
```

**Note** I haven't set the value of `Environment` in setter because this value will be in `config.json` so there is no need to set this value in setter.

For more details have a look at this [article](http://blog.jsinh.in/asp-net-5-configuration-microsoft-framework-configurationmodel/#.VWcNi8-qqko).

Answer (score 0):

Try use `OptionsModel`. it allows strong typed model binding to configuration.

```
class AppSettings
{
   public string SomeSetting {get;set;}
}

var configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile("config.json");
var opt = ConfigurationBinder.Bind<AppSettings>(configuration);
opt.SomeSetting
```

Example:
https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel.Test/OptionsTest.cs#L80