# ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and Configs for dnx451 dependencies

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core

I am quite new to ASP.NET vNext and I am struggling with the configuration of a depenedency in my project. 
I have defined some dependencies in my dnx451 section of the project.json. They usually load their settings from an old style app.config file via ConfigurationManager like

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myConfigKey" value="myConfigValue" />
</appSettings>
```

and

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConfigKey"];
```

I understood how to configure the application in basic ASP.NET 5 like described here: [ASP.NET 5 (vNext) - Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738344/asp-net-5-vnext-configuration)

So my question is: Is there a way to let my dependent assembly know their configuration values?

Best regards

Comment: Look at [the place](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#options-config-objects) of documentation. It's not full clear what you mean with "a way to let my dependent assembly know their configuration values". Do you decided your application in class library which need to access to some section of `appconfig.json`? What interface you have to it? Can you just forward the part of the global configuration to the class library?

Comment: ASP.NET 5 documentation [it is recommended that you only instantiate an instance of Configuration in your application’s Startup class](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#getting-and-setting-configuration-settings), but you can use `new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("PathToMyConfigKey")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I do not have influence on those class libraries and the load their config the old fashoined way as described above. They were built to have direct access to the app.config and get their appSettings from there. I just need to know if there is a way to load those settings.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't full understand your question. If you removed `dnxcore50` and use only `dnx451` in your project then it works using the same .NET Framework 4.5.1 which you knows. If some component access directly to some XML file and read directly some myConfigKey then it will get the value. It's difficult to say something if we write just about "some legacy dependent assembly" as "black box". Do you tried to use it? Do you have some problem? Nobody can say definitively that some unknown old code works correctly in the changed environment.

Comment: But we are getting closer ;). I did remove dnxcore50. Here is what I do not understand till now: Can I add an app.config to my project as well? Actually I never tried to add an app.config to an ASP.NET 5 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer is given here: [web.config in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022320/web-config-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)

Just like Oleg said in an upper comment.

I can place an app.config next to my DLL and can configure my third party libs like that.

Thanks for the answers anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the values into the assemblies via constructor or property injection. A DI container such as AutoFac will help you do this easily, but you can do it without using poor man's DI.

```
public class SomeClassInAssembly
{
    private readonly string _configValue;

    public SomeClassInAssembly(string configValue)
    {
        _configValue = configValue;
    }

    // Some method that now has access to your variable

}
```

Then in the calling application just retrieve from config in the usual way and pass it in

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, as I do not have access to the class libraries and as they load their settings directly from the app.config in the way described above, I cannot inject the configuration into the class.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the library which consumes `ConfigurationManager` directly will not work under ASP.NET 5. You need to update the library or make them update it to abstract the configuration part away so that you can pass the config programmatically.